# How to use "global variables" in rsyslogd v8?

Tags: rsyslog

The documentation for the "mmsequence" plugin for rsyslog 8.16.0 says:

> **This module is deprecated** in v8 and solely provided for backward compatibility reasons. It was written as a work-around for missing
>   global variable support in v7. Global variables are available in v8,
>   and at some point in time this module will entirely be removed.
>
> **Do not use this module for newly crafted config files.** Use global variables instead.

However, I see no reference to global variables in the rsyslogd v8 help documentation either as shipped with the package, nor the online version.

Please, how do I use a global variable in the modern expression-based format for rsyslogd v8?

Answer (score 1):

And... I finally found the answer buried in a blog post.  It seems that global variables are prefixed with $/ in rsyslog v8 configuration.

`set $/myvar = 1;`

Comment: Can you post a link to the blog post you are referring to?

Comment: Not sure if this was the original, but here's the blog post defining the proposal:

https://rainer.gerhards.net/2013/10/a-proposal-for-rsyslog-state-variables.html

Comment: So how do you implement `mmsequence` (e.g. to have a global message counter) using global variables?